# Transposing keyframes or recursive keyframing in AE

Tags: after-effects, keyframes

I want to embed a clip inside of itself inside of itself inside of itself. I have a clip of a person using a tablet, and I want the same clip displayed *on* the tablet. I have tracked the motion of the tablet in Mocha and mapped the clip onto the tablet. Rather than track the the motion of the tablet in the video on the first tablet, I'm curious if I can just copy the movement keyframes but transpose them for the movement of the first tablet? Can keyframes be transposed relative to another set of keyframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your composition twice. Let's call these 1, 2 and 3

In **2**, replace the embedded clip layer with **3**. With <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down and the embedded clip layer being selected, drag **3** on top of it. In **1**, replace its embedded clip layer with **2**.

I assume that the dimensions of the source clip and the composition are the same, else some transformation will be required.